# CraftCMS Output Different - HTML/CSS to Twig/PCSS

Tags: craftcms

Good day, I've got a problem with CraftCMS FrontEnd side. I created a plain html/css layout using SemanticUI and then tried using it to CraftCMS. However, when I use it in CraftCMS (twig/pcss) ~ The output are always different.
Here's a the whole styles.pcss file: https://pastebin.com/STW5P9FL

Tried converting the css file I created into scss format using online converters.

```
  .third.panel {
    .ui.left {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10% 0 0 0;
      .ui.huge.header {
        .ui.header {
          font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
      }
    }
    .ui.right {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      .ui.huge.header {
        .ui.header {
          font-size: 1.3rem;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: If my answer was of help to you, kindly mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The file you linked to is .css, your code example is not. Browsers cannot parse .pcss files, neither can Craft, you need to use [PostCss](https://postcss.org/) to transpile that file to .css to create something a browser can understand.